# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'en_core_web_sm'

Tags: python, spacy

I'm new to python and have been stuck on one issue:
I have to execute a python file in visual studio code, which is giving me an error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'en_core_web_sm'`
,

even though I have downloaded en-core-web-sm  2.2.5.

Please, help me to solve this issue
Thanks and Regards,

```py
import spacy  
import re
import json
import pymongo 
import datetime
import sys
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

from pathlib import Path
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Comment: As a new contributor you might be interested in [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 11):

You can install a downloaded python `whl` file via the [python package manager pip](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#pip) e.g.:

`pip install en_core_web_sm-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl`

You can download a `en_core_web_sm` from this page:

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.1.0

The example from the [spacy](https://spacy.io/) front page looks easy, have you tried the commented first lines in your terminal?
Example from spacy page:

```py
# pip install -U spacy
# python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
import spacy

# Load English tokenizer, tagger, parser and NER
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Lines to execute in terminal before usage in python:

```sh
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Please check also the [docs from spacy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy) and how to install and [download model packages.](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#-download-model-packages).

Maybe you need to install the whole [spacy package](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#pip) and not only one sub package e.g.:

```sh
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install spacy
```

A good starting point to learn python is reading some docs ;-)
Maybe this can help too:

[What Are Python Wheels and Why Should You Care?](https://realpython.com/python-wheels/)

A full working example can be found on the [spacy docs page for this package](https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_sm) too. Note it uses the package version `3.1.0`.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en.examples import sentences 

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(sentences[0])
print(doc.text)
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you haven't imported the package. Import that and try once

```
import en_core_web_sm

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

If not working still, try re-installing it again as shown below :

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz
```

or

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

along with

```
python -m spacy download en
```

Either of these should work.

Answer (score 1):

for me this code works :

```
!pip install spacy -q
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm -q
```

and

```
# Text modules
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
```

It's ok for JupyterNotebook and google colab

Answer (score 1):

### My dear friend

I been trying to solve this issue for an hour... tried everything and the simple code block down below solved all my problems 0_0

```
import spacy

spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_sm")
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and used the following steps to resolve it:

1. Go to the command prompt and activate the environment for which you need the `"en_core_web_sm"`, using the command:

   `conda activate <your environment name>`

if you are using the base environment then no need for the above steps (provided you've set the environment variables.

2. Run the following command:
   `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

In my case it downloaded

> en-core-web-sm==3.2.0

Voila,you are done...

Answer (score 0):

This solution from @amit finally worked for me!

1. Go to command prompt
2. Run command: `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Afterwards it showed this:

> Successfully installed en-core-web-sm-3.3.0
>
> ✔ Download and installation successful
>
> You can now load the package via spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

3. Go back to python and load
   `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`